# How to automatically change opening houres on an website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got an little problem.. I would like to display an new opening hours on a website. It need to be automatically updated every 24 hour at midnight.

Hope someone can help me :)

Here is the opening hours: 
Monday:  10:00 - 21:00
Tirsdag: 10:00 - 21:00
Onsdag:  10:00 - 21:00
Torsdag: 10:00 - 21:00
Fredag:  10:00 - 01:00
Lørdag:  10:00 - 01:00
Søndag:  12:00 - 23:00

Comment: Why would you want to automatically update hours everyday? Seems like a hassle for customers. Do you have any code you could share?

Comment: If you just need to display different hours based on a week day you can write javascript for that.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Amandus! You'll have to help us help you. You're saying the opening hours change every 24 hours, yet you provide us with a set of fixed opening times. I'm confused. Also, I don't understand what exactly is your question? Where is your code? What have you tried, what did or didn't work?

Comment: Where should the opening hours come from? Which possibilities do you have: database, php, asp.net, HTML5, .. Why do you need to change it daily/hourly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I ahve tryed displaying random text this way, but I want to display opening hours on an specified day.


here is the code:


<div class="tid" id="quote"></div>
  
  <script>
   (function() {
    var quotes = [
    {
     text: "text1",
    },
    {
     text: "text2",
    },
    {
     text: "text3",
    },
    {
     text: "text4",
    },
    {
     text: "text5",
    }
   ];
    var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>';
   })();
  </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script>
        var d = new Date();
        var days = ["Søndag 12:00 - 23:00","Mandag 10:00 - 21:00","Tirsdag 10:00 - 21:00","Onsdag 10:00 - 21:00","Torsdag 10:00 - 21:00","Fredag 10:00 - 01:00","Lørdag 10:00 - 01:00"];
        document.getElementById("opening-hours").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()];
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to display new hours depending on what day it is.
You can store the data in an object:

```
[
   {
     // for monday
     startTime: XXX,
     endTime: YYY
   },
   {
     // for tuesday
     startTime: XXX,
     endTime: YYY
   }
   ...
]
```

Then you can get the current day using javascript date object, and pick the correct values from the object.

```
new Date().getDay()
```